# How to sort into X bins Y times with minimum overlap?

Tags: algorithms, discrete-optimization, sorting, combinatorial-designs

Let's say I'm hosting a series of dinner parties for a total of $N$ guests. Each night, there are $X$ tables, and we are meeting for a total of $Y$ nights.

I want to preassign the guests to tables such that they are able to meet as many new people as possible over the series of all nights, i.e. they have as few as possible repeat table buddies.

Is there a formula or algorithm for for sorting $N$ items into $X$ bins, $Y$ times, such that there is as little overlap as possible?

P.S. This is a real-world problem for me! In my case, $N=$ about 40, $X=4$, and $Y=4$.

Comment: Unfortunately, (for example) $~\displaystyle \left[4^{(40)}\right]^4 = \left[x^N\right]^y~$ is far greater than $~\displaystyle (10)^8~$ which seems to be the ballpark neighbor of simulations that a typical PC can handle.  Therefore, using a PC to spin through the possible seatings seems problematic.

Comment: Re previous comment, $~\displaystyle \binom{40}{10} \times \binom{30}{10} \times \binom{20}{10} \times \binom{10}{10} ~\approx 10^{(21)}~$ so taking the shortcut that on each night, each table will get $10$ people is still far too onerous for a PC.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks. But I was assuming that rather than iterating through all possibilities, you could use some kind of sorting heuristic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $\binom{40}{2}=780$ pairs of people.  With $4$ rounds of $4$ tables of $10$ people, you cannot cover more than $4^2\binom{10}{2}=720$ pairs.

[Good-Enough Golfers](https://goodenoughgolfers.com/) quickly finds a schedule that contains $96$ "conflicts" (repeated pairs) and hence covers $720 - 2 \cdot 96 = 528$ pairs.

Via integer linear programming, I found a schedule that covers $624$ pairs (not necessarily optimal because I terminated the solver):

```
{5,16,20,23,27,30,32,34,36,37}
{2,3,8,11,19,22,24,28,33,39}
{6,7,10,12,15,17,25,29,31,40}
{1,4,9,13,14,18,21,26,35,38}

{2,3,13,14,16,18,25,29,34,36}
{5,7,20,22,24,28,31,35,38,40}
{6,10,11,12,19,21,26,32,37,39}
{1,4,8,9,15,17,23,27,30,33}

{13,14,15,17,18,22,24,28,32,37}
{1,4,5,9,11,19,20,25,29,39}
{2,3,6,10,12,23,27,30,35,38}
{7,8,16,21,26,31,33,34,36,40}

{11,15,16,17,19,34,35,36,38,39}
{21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30}
{5,6,8,10,12,13,14,18,20,33}
{1,2,3,4,7,9,31,32,37,40}
```